# What is a binary encoded PDF?

Tags: php, http, rest

I am currently trying to connect to a REST Api which isn't documented very well. 
I need to Upload a PDF to a specific URL using the Http POST Request.

The Api documentation says:

> POST to this request with a binary encoded pdf.

It doesn't work and I wonder what they mean by "binary encoded pdf".

What I did was:

```
$pdf = base64_encode(file_get_contents("test.pdf"));
$result = $restClient->post('/api/upload/', $pdf);
```

Result:

> 400 - Bad Request

Note: The REST Client works for all other requests. I just don't seem to know what is meant by "binary encoded".

Http Header "Content-type" is also correctly set to "application/pdf"

Comment: Perhaps they had problems with people sending trinary PDFs? If that's a sample of its documentation, I'd say that API's developers need to be smacked with a cluebat a few times.

Comment: @Marc: No, they were probably being sent unary PDFs. Now that's useless!

Comment: Check if the multipart/ POST uses `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`. Also the base64 is obviously uneeded then. Try `application/octet-stream` as content type, because that's often what people mean or expect when they say "binary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a strange way to say "as is - do *not* encode with base64".